# Rails - How to validate form with JS and submit using Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm building functionality that lets users comment on content in my web app. Right now I have a simple javascript form validation that checks to see if the comment is not blank and is more than 10 characters long. If it isn't then it prevents form submission using `preventDefault()` and displays an error message on the screen. If there are no errors, it allows the form to submit and reloads the page with the new comment.

However I want to make it so that when you submit the form and there are no errors, it uses Ajax to submit the data to the database and then use jQuery to insert the comment on the page so there is no page reloading.

I have it set up on my form like so:

```
<%= form_for(@comment, html: { class: "form-general" }, remote: true) do |f| %>
```

and have set up my controller to respond to that request like so:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to request.referer }
  format.js
end
```

However there is one problem, that is when there is an error in the comment. For example if the comment is less than 10 characters, the error messages are generated by my javascript validation appropriately, however the Ajax request has already fired even if there is an error.

How do I make it so that only if the comment is valid, the Ajax request is sent off?

Comment: Could you post the JS code that fires your AJAX?

Comment: Rails handles it with the `remote: true` no? So the form is submitted asynchronously without the need to write any JS yourself?

Comment: Ah, didn't see that there. Could you just trigger the Ajax call manually since you're already using JS once your form validation passes?

Comment: Yea I was originally planning on just triggering Ajax manually once the form validation passes, but this way catches browsers with JS turned off I believe.

Comment: Maybe take a look at [Ajax local events](http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/) such as `before:send` that might be able to prevent the sending. Not quite sure how to bind that to the form that uses `remote:true` though.